# Simple pattern rule in Makefile not always matched

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have this very simple Makefile to create plots from tab-separated data files:

```
%s.png: %s.tsv
    Rscript make-plots.r $< $@
```

I have a file `genus.tsv` from which I want to make a plot. This is done as follows:

```
$ make -v
GNU Make 3.81
$ make genus.png
Rscript make-plots.r genus.tsv genus.png
```

That works as expected. Here comes the strange part. If I create a copy `test.tsv` from `genus.tsv`, and I try to make a plot from that, it fails for some reason:

```
$ cp genus.tsv test.tsv
$ make test.png
make: *** No rule to make target `test.png'.  Stop.
```

The same happens with any other `.png` target I've tried. I expect the [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html#Pattern-Rules) to match any `.png` target. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Your pattern rule requires the file name to end with an `s`. A pattern wildcard is `%` not `%s` (it isn't a format string). You want `%.png: %.tsv` as the pattern rule or `tests.tsv` as the file.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Wow. I've been staring at it for too long, but I did not notice that typo. Thanks!